# Magento Purchase Issue - Foreign Constraint Fails `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Problem:
When a new user attempts to checkout with a credit card on our Magento site, they are given an error 'Unable to process your order. Please try again later'. Attempting to checkout a second time succeeds.

Background:
Our Magento developer is currently out of the office. I've been tasked with remedying this problem. I have looked into it and have found the source of the problem. However, I have no experience with Magento and am unsure how to remedy the issue.

Insights:
The code comes from this controller:
`app\code\community\FI\Checkout\controllers\CheckoutControler.php`

The specific code failing is:

```
    try {
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $quote->setCheckoutMethod(Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_CUSTOMER);
        } elseif (!$sessionOrder->getAddress()->getId()) {
            $quote->setCheckoutMethod(Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_REGISTER);
        }

        $this->getOnepage()->initCheckout();
        $this->_saveAddressesFor($sessionOrder);
        $this->_subscribeCustomer($sessionOrder->getCustomer(), $this->getRequest()->getPost('subscribe', false));
        $this->_saveShippingMethod();

        $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)
            ->collectTotals();

        // save payment information
        $payment = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment');
        $this->getOnepage()->savePayment($payment);

        $redirectUrl = $quote->getPayment()->getCheckoutRedirectUrl();
        if ($redirectUrl) {
            $response->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
            return $this->_respondWith($response);
        }

        if(!isset($data['address']['billing_check_same'])){
            $billingAddressData = $data['billingaddress'];
//                print_r($billingAddressData);exit;
            $bilingaddress = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
            $bilingaddress->setData('firstname',$billingAddressData['firstname'])
                    ->setData('lastname',$billingAddressData['lastname'])
                    ->setData('telephone',$billingAddressData['telephone'])
                    ->setData('postcode',$billingAddressData['postcode'])
                    ->setData('country_id',$billingAddressData['country_id'])
                    ->setData('region',$billingAddressData['region']);
                    if(isset($billingAddressData['region_id'])){
                    $bilingaddress->setData('region_id',$billingAddressData['region_id']);
                    }else{
                        $bilingaddress->unsetData('region_id');
                    }
                    $bilingaddress->setData('city',$billingAddressData['city'])
                    ->setData('street',array($billingAddressData['street'][0],$billingAddressData['street'][1]))
            ->save();
        }


        // save order
        $this->_placeOrder();
        $redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()
            ->getCheckout()
            ->getRedirectUrl();

        $quote->setIsActive(!empty($redirectUrl))->save();
        $sessionOrder->drop();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $hasError = true;
        $response->setErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        $hasError = true;
        $response->setErrorMessage(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Unable to process your order. Please try again later'));
    }
```

The sql error thrown is:

```
INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` (`address_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `carrier`, `carrier_title`, `code`, `method`, `method_description`, `price`, `method_title`) VALUES ('8318', '2016-08-19 18:20:10', '2016-08-19 18:20:10', 'flatrate', 'Express 1 Week Delivery', 'flatrate_flatrate', 'flatrate', NULL, '20', NULL)
Foreign key constraint fails for table `stagewsp`.`sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`:
,
CONSTRAINT `FK_B1F177EFB73D3EDF5322BA64AC48D150` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_quote_address` (`address_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Whats getting me is:

- Only new customers see this issue.
- Purchasing a second time succeeds.

I understand the quote address is failing to save but I'm not sure why.